# Powershell Error: Exception Calling "Approve" with "2" argument(s): Value cannot be null

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I'm writing a powershell script to automate WSUS. One of the functions approves non-superseded updates to a sandbox testing computer group in order to download/install them on the console. However, all updates it finds return this same error. Here is the code for my definitions and the approval function:

```
[String]$updateServer1 = hostname
[Boolean]$useSecureConnection = $False
[Int32]$portNumber = 8530
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$updateServer = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($updateServer1,$useSecureConnection,$portNumber)
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$u = $updateServer.GetUpdates($updatescope)
$install = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateApprovalAction]::Install
$group = $updateServer.GetComputerTargetGroups | where-object {$_.Name -eq "Update Testing"}

function Approve-Nonsuperseded {
    Write-host "Creating new Computer Group to approve updates for installation..." -foregroundcolor green
    try {
        $updateserver.CreateComputerTargetGroup("Update Testing") 
        }
    catch {
        Write-host "Update Group already exists. Moving on..." -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    $count = 0
    Write-host "Approving new updates for installation..." -foregroundcolor green
    foreach ($u2 in $u )
        {
        if ($u2.IsDeclined -ne 'True' -and $u2.IsSuperseded -ne 'True' -and $u2.CreationDate -ge $PatchDay)
            {
                write-host Approving Update : $u2.Title
                $u2.Approve($install,$group)
                $count = $count + 1
            }
        }
    write-host Total Approved Updates: $count
}
```

It returns all the correct updates that are meant to be approved, but always gives me that same error on the $u2.Approve($install,$group) line. I'd appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: Check $group to see if it is $null.

Comment: It is not. Returns the correct group. I even tested it inside the function after the count variable in case that was the issue. EDIT: I noticed there was a "." missing on that line, but after adding it in I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: ahhhhh wait a sec, you were right all along. Forgot to add the "()" before the pipe. Doh. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`$u2` should be a string and not an variable. Try using `$u2.Approve("Install",$group)`

The [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateApprovalAction] namespace only provides the options ;)

Comment: $u2 is an object assigned in the foreach, you probably meant $install. The value of $install is an enum, that matches the argument parameter type for that method. When you pass a string, as you stated, the conversion is done to the proper enum.